# How to set circular progressbar inside button in android

Tags: android, button

I want to make circular progress bar inside button. 
but I don't want to use library like `dmytrodanylyk/circular-progress-button, etc..`

I think this solution is used `drawable`.

so, i make `circular_progress.xml`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="1"
        android:toDegrees="360" >

        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="8"
            android:useLevel="false" >
            <size
                android:height="48dip"
                android:width="48dip" />

            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#f0f0f0"
                android:centerY="0.50"
                android:endColor="#000000"
                android:startColor="#ffffff"
                android:type="sweep"
                android:useLevel="false" />
        </shape>

    </rotate>
```

and,

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Log In"
                android:layout_below="@+id/passwordWrapper"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SignButton"
                android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/circular_progress"
                />
```

[image]

but, progress bar is stopped.

second solution is to make custom button class having progressbar.

but i don't know to make custom button class having progressbar.

Answer (score 6):

Use ProgressBar inside your button like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Log In"
    android:layout_below="@+id/passwordWrapper"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SignButton"
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    />
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in your activity initialize the ProgressBar like this

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
```

and add this when you want the ProgressBar to be visible

```
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and then add this when you want to hide your ProgressBar

```
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```